# How to read json file and filter the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, fs

I am stacked since 7 days in a simple function in javascript ... but i can not find the soluction!

The problem is this: I have to read a json file, and filter the result...

This is my server-side script for read the file:

```
function testing(email) 
{
    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('test.json');
    var mydata = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    console.log("parse:"+ mydata);

    const value = email;
    const result = mydata.filter(email);
    console.log("result: " + result);

    if(result == 'undefined')
    {
        return(false);
    }
    else
    {
        return(true);
    }
};
```

This is my json file:

```
[
{
    "1":"black@gmail.com"
},
{
    "2":"bad@gmail.com"
}
{
    "3":"strangemail@gmail.com"
}
]
```

Comment: What is the condition for filtering?

Comment: What is the value of `email`? You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: "This is my json file" — That is really very oddly structured data. Why isn't it a plain array of strings?

Comment: @ontananza condition of filtering is "value" ... i guess

Comment: @Quentin ye for sure, i will provied it in a sec! by the way the vaule of email is a string passed as parameter when you try to call this function!
i am studying javascript right now ... i don't know what is it "plain array of strings"

Comment: "vaule of email is a string" — Then why are you passing it to `filter`? Have you looked at the documentation for `filter`? It takes a **function** as an argument.

Comment: " i don't know what is it "plain array of strings"" — It's where the values in the array are strings and not objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JSON data structure is rather odd, with a different key in each object, but if that's what you're stuck with, here's how it can be handled.

```js
// a string to stand in for JSON fie:
const jsonStr = `[
  {"1":"black@gmail.com"},
  {"2":"bad@gmail.com"},
  {"3":"strangemail@gmail.com"}
]`;

function testing(email) {
  var mydata = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

  const result = mydata.filter(obj => {
    // search every property in object for email, since the
    // source JSON data doesn't have consistent keys
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if (value === email) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(result); // [ { '2': 'bad@gmail.com' } ]
  return result.length > 0;
}

let example = testing("bad@gmail.com");
console.log(example); // true
```

Comment: It works ... that was what i looking for ... really thank you man ... you really helped me !

Answer (score 0):

Every element of json array should contain the same consistent key and if you need index, index should be another key ie: 
`const myData = [{"idx": 1, "email": "black@gmail.com"}, {"idx": 2, "email": "bad@gmail.com"}, {"idx": 3, "email": "strangemail@gmail.com"}]`

And then you could filter data using the expression as

`const result = myData.filter((x) => x.email === email);`

Result should be something like:

`[{"idx": 1, "email": "black@gmail.com"}]`

Comment: i am gonna test it right now! Thank you man, really appreciate it <3